# illuminate vendors not found in PhpStorm since Laravel 8.36 upgrade

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, laravel-8

Since I've updated to Laravel 8.36 PhpStorm can't autocomplete and doesn't find the vendors... what's the problem ?

[image]

Comment: Did you upgrade your PhpStorm to 2021.1 at the same time / recently? If so -- please try `File | Invalidate Caches`, select top 2 options there and restart IDE from that screen; once project is re-opened let the re-indexing to complete and see how it will behave then.

Comment: Yes I've upgraded to 2021.1. I try this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have recently upgraded your IDE to 2021.1 version then please do the following:

1. `File | Invalidate Caches...`
2. Select top 2 options (maybe only 1st will be enough, but better use both)
3. Use `Invalidate and Restart` button there
4. After the IDE will restart, open the project and let re-indexing to complete.

[image]

**P.S.** On Mac the screen visually looks a bit better than my Windows 10:
[image]